# Probability of exposure to an epidemic disease

Tags: probability

Given the growth rate of an epidemic in a particular city or region, in how many days would the probability of an average resident of the region getting exposed approach 50% (a different number is also fine if this is unrealistic)?

One variable we can take into consideration is the average number of people a resident is coming into contact with daily.

(The idea behind this question is to give people an indication of how the growth of the coronavirus epidemic might affect them -- specifically how soon they might get exposed if they follow rigorous quarantine as opposed to no quarantine).

Comment: Does the growth rate describe the number of infections per day? Or? What is the source of randomness here: number of cases per day? The chance of infection upon interaction? we need a more precise setup.

Comment: Growth rate would describe the number of infections per day. Source of randomness would be chances of infection upon interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that the number of infected is an exponential function of pandemic period (measured in days) and the probability of getting infected equals to the proportion $$\frac{\# infected}{\# total}$$, then to calculate the number of days required you need to solve the following equation: $$\frac{e^x}{\# total} = 0.5$$ which gives you $x = ln (0.5*\# total)$ Intuitively, in this simple setup the number of days only depends on the population size. If you want to illustrate what happens under alternative quarantine regiments, you need to consider alternative specifications of the function for the number of infected. For instance, if you consider the function $\#infected = \sqrt{x}$ where $x$ is, once again, days of pandemic, then your equation becomes $$\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\# total} = 0.5 \implies x = (0.5*\# total)^2$$ For population size = 10, if the growth is exponential (no-quarantine regime), you will get to 0.5 probability in 1.6 days; for square root growth (flattened curve) you will get to 0.5 probability in 25 days.

Comment: In the none to minimal isolation plan that we were in in the U.S (and other places, with adjustment for population) during initial outbreak, half of us should have it within the space of a month from $t_0$! Since the testing has been so terrible (as of today, I read 60k tested and 80k confirmed, very roughly, in the U.S.), together with any simple but basically valid model like this, that most of us actually have it by now...